# Using regex for removing certain elements from a string

Tags: regex, string

I'm using a string to store a quadratic equation and then resolve it via quadratic formula.

So i require a regex for removing elements like x and/or x[^2], but i really i don't know how to create a regex unless i use replace for each symbol/letter/number i want to remove.

Ex:

- Input: 2x^2+4x+6
- Output: 2 4 6

Comment: can you give an example of sample input and output

Comment: Done, i modify the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a regex that matches a quadratic polynomial:

```
^(?:([+-]?\d+)x\^2)?(?:([+-]?\d+)x)?([+-]?\d+)?$
```

Group 1 is the coefficient of x^2, Group 2 is the coefficient of x, Group 3 is the constant. A group with an empty string means it's a 1. You just get those groups and plug them into the quadratic formula. Remember to remove all whitespace from the string before using the regex.

Note that this regex matches things like `6x3` and interprets it as `6x+3`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/i0RNha/1)

Comment: but it removes everything from the string instead of giving me 3 values(Already updated the post to see the output)

Comment: @Netox you don’t replace. You should access the captured values. Look up how to do that in whatever language you are using.

Comment: In my example of the input, instead of 2x^2+4x+6, i use as an input x^2+4x+6 i add in the regex |[x] after \d+? So i can express OR character x

Comment: I just solve it. I found another problem if the user adds "+" OR "-"  after the number or the x, it doesn't recognize it